# Identifying a passive voice usage of a past participle

Tags: parts-of-speech, passive-voice, past-participles

I read in a Stack Exchange answer that the tip to determine whether a past participle is acting as part of passive voice construction in a particular sentence or not is:

If it describes an action that the subject cannot do by itself, it is a passive  construction.

For example:

- The mouse was trapped.
- The park was covered with snow.
- Mr. Smith is known to everyone in this town.

Can the above tip be taken as a rule of thumb to distinguish where a past participle is being used as verb from where it is being used as an adjective ? Otherwise, it seems the confusion persists between active and stative use of the past participle.

Comment: 1, it is not "a thumb rule", it is "a rule of thumb" This is a set phrase = "good, general guidance", thus it is **almost** always true. Have a look at https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-participial-adjective-1691486

Comment: Do you mean 'agent' / 'natural cause', the actual doer (/ sustainer etc) of an action, rather than 'subject'? In the transformational pair _Jill kicked the ball_  <==>  _The ball was kicked by Jill_, the **subject** (a word or group of words) switches from _Jill_ to _[t]he ball_, while the agent, the kicker, is the redoubtable Jill, bless her  (ie an actual person) in each case.

Comment: In your first example, we have an inherently ambiguous sentence. Without context, you **can't** know whether the sentence describes an event or a state. / Your second example is also inherently ambiguous, though from experience most practised readers would (without context) expect this to be a reporting of a state rather than an event. The event reading is slightly jarring; wouldn't _most_ of a town say be covered with snow in a snowstorm? // 'Be trapped' and 'be covered' often have either the stative or dynamic (= get V-ed) readings. But only the stative sense ...

Comment: is possible in your third example. A possible punctive reading is 'Suddenly, Mr Smith became known by everyone in the town.' I'd say 'be known to' is virtually fossilised, a multi-word verb. The passive transformation of 'Jill knows Jane' is 'Jane is known **by** Jill'.

Comment: Dear Edwin, ambiguity persists even with contexts .somewhere i read that "very" test can ascertain the adjectival use of past participle.So, how does the learners like me reconcile with definitive differentiator? Shall be grateful if you can guide further. Thanks